# How can I use request module in Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark

this is the code I used.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Session()
    toGet = s.get

    spark = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("PythonDockerRepoStat")\
        .getOrCreate()

    lines = spark.read.text('/data/urls.txt').rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
    res = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split("\n"))\
        .map(lambda x: toGet(x))
    output = res.collect()
    print(output)
```

However, I got this error: *ImportError: No module named requests.sessions*

Comment: Launch the pyspark shell and `import requests`. It will work.

Answer (score 2):

When launching Spark jobs all dependencies have to be accessible for:

- driver interpreter.
- executor interpreter.

Extending path:

```
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
```

will affect only local driver interpreter. To set executor environment variables you can:

- modify `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`
- use `spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` configuration option (for example by editing `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` or setting corresponding `SparkConf` key.

At the same time you should make sure that `requests` is installed / accessible on every worker node (if not using local / pseudo-distributed mode).

Comment: It makes sense, though I did not try.

Comment: @Victor.Li Would you consider accepting the answer? Thanks! :)